# WSO2 - SaaS Service Provider Permissions in a Multitenant environment

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to configure the following scenario in WSO2

- Have a SaaS Enabled service provider which specifies certain application permissions (in the carbon.super tenant)
- Have those permissions show up in the Role editor for each tenant (such that each tenant can specify what application permissions are assigned to what role)

This is assuming that the permissions will be part of the info provided when authentication succeeds (such that the permissions can be used in my application).

Is this possible and if so, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible. When SaaS Enabled the Service provider created from one tenant can be accessed across tenants. But when it comes to role-based permissions each tenant space is isolated. When you create a certain application with permissions for a super tenant it will be stored under the **Super Admin Permissions** (super tenant level) on the permission tree. When you are logging in as tenant WSO2 IS is using the permissions configured under the **Admin Permissions** (tenant level). So if you want to see the permissions in the Role editor of each tenant you might need to configure it separately for each tenant.

Please refer to the following documentation for further clarification https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Role-based+Permissions

Comment: So the "solution" would be that my service provider (and the permissions associated with my app) would need to be duplicated across tenants? Seems crappy.

Any chance this is in the feature backlog?

Comment: Seems like you haven't got the point clearly. We are clear that you have a SaaS enabled service provider. What do you mean by service provider specifies certain application permissions in the carbon.super tenant?

Comment: Normally in WSO2 IS we have roles with certain permissions assigned. If the role is created for a **carbon.super** tenant we can assign permission from either Super Admin Permissions or Admin Permissions or both. Then we associate this role with a user created under this tenant. When we configure service provider we can restrict role-based access by modifying the **authn_role_based_policy_template** to create a new policy to restrict access as per the required role.

Comment: Assume now we have a service provider created under the **carbon.super** tenant with role-based access control associated with **role1**, with **user1** associated with **role1**. So any user with **role1** under the **carbon.super** tenant can access this service provider. Since SaaS is enabled any users under the other tenants with **role1** can also access the service provider. But the **role1** created under the **carbon.super** tenant won't be available under the other tenants. You might need to create this role with relevant permission for other tenants and assign users.

Comment: Here's the more general requirement/question. Can I define arbitrary permissions in one place (for all tenants), and assign those permissions to roles (per tenant)? For example: 

Let's say I want to define a "ViewQuestions" permission (which I will use to secure the Questions screen my app). Tenant_1 can assign this permission to their "Question Viewer" role, while Tenant_2 can assign this permission to their "Smart person" role.

Comment: Accepting the answer given